# SSH + DIR command on remote windows machine

Tags: ssh, windows

I installed OpenSSH on windows server 2008 r2 and exported my public key there. I can connect normally without typing a password, I can even run the DIR command already in the command I use to connect:

```
ssh user@ip-address "dir c:\testfolder"
```

However, running the DIR command on a directory with spaces in the name:

```
ssh user@ip-address "dir c:\test folder"
```

Does not work.

Would anyone know the correct way to run the dir command on a folder with spaces in the name? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried quoting it (being certain to escape the quotes properly, as well as the '\' in the path name... Windows will usually accept '/' instead of '\'): `ssh user@ip-address "dir \"c:/test folder\""`

Comment: That's exactly what I did.  It worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

a friend who is a programmer taught me how to solve this. How do I need the path to be printed in the windows shell with double quotes like this:

```
"c:\teste folder"
```

And the double quotes already serve to send the command to Windows via SSH, to send the double quotes to the windows shell you need to use the backslash with double quotes `\"`, the command would look like:

```
ssh user@ip-address "dir \"c:\teste folder\""
```

It stays as a help for those who have the same doubts in the future.

[Reference material](https://www.shellscript.sh/escape.html)

Comment: Couldn't you have used single quotes on the outside and non-escaped double quotes on the inside? `'dir "c:\teste foldr"'`  Easier to read (and type) that way.

Comment: This I have not tested.  Although it's already working correctly, I'll test it out of curiosity.

Comment: In this case, it will work. However, in bash, single quotes prevent expansion of enclosed variables, such as $PATH. That often leads to other problems when you start to assume you can use \' and \" interchangeably, like you can in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was meant to be directed @Kusalananda 's comment.

Comment: I suggested using the quotes in this particular way because there were no variables that the local shell needed to expand in the argument to `dir`.

Answer (score 1):

First, always be certain to check quoting, the rules in effect for the shell (the command is executed in bash locally, but the remote side may use something else, such as cmd.exe on Windows) regarding quoting, and when to escape quotes you need to pass along explicitly. Also, the outer pair is often stripped/removed during parsing.

With the command `ssh user@ip-address "dir c:\\testfolder"`, bash sees three parts to the command:

```
ssh
user@ip-address
dir c:\test folder
```

Note specifically bash does NOT include the quotes around the last item! That is because at this stage, bash is assuming you are using the quotes to tell bash itself to interpret the quoted text as one part (stored in one string in bash's memory space).

When bash hands the command off to ssh, ssh sees the last two parts: `user@ip-address` and `dir c:\test folder`. shh uses the first part to determine where to connect, and once connected, passes the second part exactly as is to the remote end--rememebr, however, the quotes have already been removed.

On the remote end, sshd (the ssh daemon/service), receives that, and passes it on to cmd.exe (since this is the Windows side), as... Not two, but three parts:

```
dir
c:\test
folder
```

Which was not what was intended. So you need to ensure the quotes get passed along from command to command, using escaping as needed--Some commands strip quotes while processing, while others pass them on as-is.

So the final command, properly quoted and escaped, is:

```
ssh user@ip-address "dir \"c:/test folder\""
```

Note also that in this case, I also changed the c:\ to c:/. Modern cmd.exe will accept a / in most places, which helps avoid the ancient problem of needed to further escape any \ in the command to prevent it from being interpreted as an escape sequence itself. ("Hackers" have long used this problem as a tool for code injection, by embedding a "\n" which gets expanded to a newline character in poorly designed applications.)

If you keep the "\", you will probably need to escape it as "\\". (Note that this is a ***very*** common problem, indeed! I had to edit this post several times to get it to display correctly. This is also known as "escape hell". See the [Escape Sequence Wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) for more details.)

Other methods of handling the base problem (file names with spaces in them) exist on Windows:

- You can map a drive letter to the full path with the `subst` command. This is also often used to "shorten" very long paths:

  subst g d:/an/insanely/long/path/to/my/personal/folder/of/favorite/games

would let you use "g:" instead of always typing out the full path.

- Under NTFS in modern Windows' systems, you can use [NTFS Reparse Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point) to create Junction Points and Symbolic Links for file (and folder) names which do not have spaces in the names, but point to ones which do. Sometimes, this is the only method usable if you have a name which would require very complex quoting and escaping.